# HTML5 state management in .Net development

Tags: .net, html, state-management

HTTP has always been stateless and with the comming of HTML5, this has not changed. However, I understand that HTML5 provides a new technique for saving data at the client with 'webstorage'

What are good practices to used this technique in a save manner to persist critical session state data?

Do MS dev environments abstract the use of webstorage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "good practices"? I don't think the use of web storage can be abstracted by .NET, since it is used through a JavaScript API. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage), you can use web storage for more or less persistent storage and for session-based storage. How you should use it largely depends on the type of your application, but anything that must not get lost should be stored at the server-side, since the local storage could get lost if the user switches browsers/computers.